# Походження вислову "па па" у значенні "до побачення"

Tags: етимологія

Цікавить яким є походження вислову "па па" у значенні "до побачення". В [ЕСУМі](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/170526.html) та в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/papa) мені не вдалося знайти цього вислову. Приклад вживання:

> Па-па, па-па. Бувай, бувай. Мене не забувай, бувай.
>
> <sub>//[Пісня Олега Винника «Па-па»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or7r12VcyOM)</sub>

Comment: В українській мові такого виразу немає, є в польській і, мабуть, російській.

Comment: @Yola, в російський мові такого виразу немає. Є в польській і на заході України. Останнім часом воно поширюється й на інші частини України (частково природним чином, частково його штучно «культивують» на противагу російському _пока_).

Comment: https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/170526.html

Comment: @sasha мої російськомовні родичі так говорять. Для них це скорочення пока-пока.

Comment: @Yola, я здивований. Однак, формально це ще не означає, що вираз російський, а не український, чи більш російський, ніж український. Наприклад, я не знаю жодного російськомовного мешканця України, який би не використовував слова «буряк», «гарбуз», «паска» тощо, але по-моєму очевидно, що ці слова саме українські («правильні» російські еквіваленти: «свёкла», «тыква», «кулич»), хай вони й навіть поширилися серед російськомовних українців і мешканців близький до кордону з Україною територій.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [Етимологічно-семантичному словнику української мови](http://shron3.chtyvo.org.ua/Ohiyenko_Ivan/Etymolohichno-semantychnyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_tom_IV_P-Ya.pdf) (с.8) знаходимо:

> **Па** — кажуть дитині, прощаючись з нею в Польщі і Галичині. На Сході цього **па** не знають.

Як підтвердження цього на одному із [форумів](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/170526.html) знайшла обговорення, де користувач дописує:

> В одному польському довіднику з розвитку дитини знайшов наступне:
>
> *6 miesiąc*: Wymawia pojedyncze sylaby takie, jak „ta”, „da”, ***„pa”***, „la”.
>   ...
>   11 miesiąc: Pierwsze sensowne sylaby (np. Baba na babcię, brr na samochód, **papa** na dowidzenia).

Очевидно, цей вираз в українській мові потрапив через польські запозичення.